# Firefox adds 5mm additional margin to @page directive

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

I am writing a CSS style sheet for printing a web page and encountered the following problem:
Firefox adds additional margin to a @page directive.

Here is an example.

HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS Print Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            Print Me!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
html,
body,
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid;
}

@page
{
    size: A4 portrait;
    margin: 30mm 30mm 30mm 30mm;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This should give the page a margin of 3 cm on each side. It works for Chrome (29.0) and IE 10 but not for Firefox (21.0). When printing the page with Firefox the margin on each side is something like 35mm.

Is there a simple solution or at least an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Firefox does have default print margins; you can set them in File > Page Setup. So does it replace its default margins with those given here, or does it add these to the defaults?

Comment: It seems that margins in the @page rule overwrite the margins specified in File > Page Setup. It doesn't matter if set them to 5 or 50mm, it's allways 30+5mm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@page { /* for for all browsers except Firefox */
    size: A4 portrait;
    margin: 30mm;
    padding: 0;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() { /* only for Firefox, page margin - 5mm */  
    @page {margin:25mm;}
}
```